# How can I get just one field from a database table with SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this class:

```
public class CarConfiguration : ObservableObject
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public long CarConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With this code I know I can get all the rows:

```
public List<CarConfiguration> GetUniqueCarConfigurationNames()
{
   return db2.Table<CarConfiguration>().ToList();
}
```

But how can I get all the unique names only sorted by name?

Comment: `.Select()` and `.Distinct()` are the weapons of your choice.

Comment: Can you give an example using those.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a Query

```
return db2.Query<string>("select distinct Name from CarConfiguration order by Name").ToList();
```